# Code running longer while importing IB related libraries

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

I've installed ibpy2 and the latest version API from IB website for TWS. The below code seems to have some problem as the code is still running in the Jupyter lab notebook. I've TWS session open. I'm using a Mac.

```
from ib.opt import Connection, message
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract as C
from ib.ext.Order import Order as O
```

Not sure why this code is still running (it has been more than 10 minutes as I am posting this question)

Comment: However, when I used sublime text to write the complete code it did work though

Comment: Please try to use Spyder or Pycharm instead